# Formatting a specific row of integers to the ssn style

Tags: python, pandas

I want to format a specific column of integers to ssn format (xxx-xx-xxxx). I saw that openpyxl has builtin styles. I have been using pandas and wasn't sure if it could do this specific format.

I did see this -

```
df.iloc[:,:].str.replace(',', '')
```

but I want to replace the ',' with '-'.

```
import pandas as pd 






df = pd.read_excel('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Original.xls')


df.drop(['StartDate', 'EndDate','EmployeeID'], axis = 1, inplace=True)


df.rename(columns={'CheckNumber': 'W/E Date', 'CheckBranch': 'Branch','DeductionAmount':'Amount'},inplace=True)


df = df[['Branch','Deduction','CheckDate','W/E Date','SSN','LastName','FirstName','Amount','Agency','CaseNumber']]


ssn = (df['SSN'] # the integer column
       .astype(str)       # cast integers to string
       .str.zfill(8)      # zero-padding
       .pipe(lambda s: s.str[:2] + '-' + s.str[2:4] + '-' + s.str[4:]))

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Deductions Report.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
writer.save()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what is stopping you doing what you suggest?

Comment: how would i specify a specific column and would i make a loop for the whole column

Comment: If your column is named `ssn`, try `df['ssn'] = df['ssn'].str.replace(',', '-')`

Comment: but my string is (ex: 123456789) what would i replace?

Comment: Nothing. If there is nothing to match, it returns the same.

Comment: Try a regex match - maybe something like `'-'.join( re.match('(\d{3})(\d{2})(\d{4})',ssn).groups() )` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, see if this helps:

If you have a column of **integers** and you want to create a new one made up of **strings** in SSN (Social Security Number) format. You can try something like:

```
df['SSN'] = (df['SSN']     # the "integer" column
             .astype(int)  # the integer column
             .astype(str)  # cast integers to string
             .str.zfill(9) # zero-padding
             .pipe(lambda s: s.str[:3] + '-' + s.str[3:5] + '-' + s.str[5:]))
```

Comment: Yes this is what I am looking for but when I run it I dont see the "-". I dont get any errors.

Comment: Are you looking in the right place? The new column will be in the ssn object, not the original dataframe

Comment: I changed"ssn_integers" to the proper column name "SSN" Are all cells in a xlsx file integers or strings? Maybe I gave you the wrong information. That is the only thing i can think of.

Comment: That shouldn't really be a factor. Are you sure the dataframe is what you expect it to be? Post a sample of the dataframe in the original question. You can do that by calling df.head()

Comment: I posted what I have

Comment: You are saving the original dataframe. Like I said, the new data will be in the ssn object. If you want to to overwrite the original column, you need to attribute it to the dataframe. I've changed my answer to reflect this

Comment: This makes my numbers end in (.0) Do I have to make them back to integers?

Comment: Not possible. The new format is not integer compatible (what integer would `123-45-6789` be?). You are probably originally reading them in as floats. You can cast them to integers before you do the conversion. I've updated the answer.

Comment: i get a "Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or Inf) to integer" error. Do I have to make the column all int before?

Comment: The first cell is a string, does it skip that?

Comment: You should investigate your data. Print your df and take a look.

Comment: The issue you are having is probably because some of the fields of the xlsx are empty, so they come in as NaN. Try using pd.to_numeric instead of astype(int)

Comment: OK so I tested my code and I just noticed that when I open the xls, it reads my "ssn" they are read as floats64.

Comment: So i got it to work but this it what I changed: df = pd.read_excel('C:/Python/Python37/Files/Original.xls' dtype = {'SSN':str})

Answer (score 0):

***Setup***

Social Security numbers are nine-digit numbers using the form: `AAA-GG-SSSS`

```
s = pd.Series([111223333, 222334444])
```

```
0    111223333
1    222334444
dtype: int64
```

---

***Option 1***
Using `zip` and `numpy.unravel_index`:

```
pd.Series([
    '{}-{}-{}'.format(*el)
    for el in zip(*np.unravel_index(s, (1000,100,10000)))
])
```

***Option 2***
Using `f-strings`:

```
pd.Series([f'{i[:3]}-{i[3:5]}-{i[5:]}' for i in s.astype(str)])
```

---

Both produce:

```
0    111-22-3333
1    222-33-4444
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer:

```
df["ssn"] = df["ssn"].astype(str)
df["ssn"] = df["ssn"].str.strip()
df["ssn"] = (
    df.ssn.str.replace("(", "")
    .str.replace(")", "")
    .str.replace("-", "")
    .str.replace(" ", "")
    .apply(lambda x: f"{x[:3]}-{x[3:5]}-{x[5:]}")
)
```

This take into account rows that are partially formatted, fully formatted, or not formatted and correctly formats them all.

For Example:

```
data = [111111111,123456789,"222-11-3333","433-3131234"]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['ssn'])
```

Gives you:
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QwSj.png)

After the code you then get:
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2XYo.png)